# Migrate H2 1.3.172 database to 1.4.185 "Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file *** [90048-185] 90048/90048"

Tags: java, database, h2

I tried opening a database file which correctly works in H2 1.3.172 with H2 1.4.185 and I get a not very reassuring: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2048"

I therefore try an export with

```
java -cp h2-latest.jar org.h2.tools.Recover
```

and an import into a new database with

```
java -cp h2-latest.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url jdbc:h2:./mydb.db -user sa -script mydb.sql
```

and the export works ok, however trying to connect to the database with h2-latest.jar returns:

```
Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file "mydb.db" [90048-185] 90048/90048
```

so I'm stuck with migration, apparently I have to stick with 1.3 version.

Comment: I believe v1.4 uses MVStore subsystem as a default store format, so, you must explicitly connect with ;MVCC=FALSE (see: http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the same. If you can put it as an answer and explain how to import into a new database and specifying to not use the MVCC format I'll accept it.